# Shortcut Key to Move From VBA Immediate Window to Code Window

Tags: vba, keyboard-shortcuts

I know I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to move the cursor to the immediate window. Is there a different shortcut key to move the cursor back to the code?

Comment: GSerg and Alex K's answers are both correct.  I combined Alex's answer with an Autohotkey script to turn the `Ctrl + G` command into a "toggle" that switches back and forth between code and immediate window.  I posted the Autohotkey code as a separate answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>1</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

Assuming VBA in Office; <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: This works under most circumstances, but if you are looking at a userform and press Ctrl+G, pressing F7 will move you to the code module behind the form, not back to the form.

Comment: ... which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett: indeed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I know, my comment was meant as a FYI.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone out there using AutoHotKey, I incorporated Alex K's solution into the Autohotkey script I run whenever I log on:

```
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability

;***  ;VBA IDE
#IfWinActive ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk ;only execute if VBA IDE is active win
^g::   ; Ctl + g: Toggle immediate window
    WinGet, WindowUniqueID, ID, A
    ControlGetFocus, ControlID, ahk_id %WindowUniqueID%
    ControlGet, ControlHwnd, Hwnd,, %ControlID%, ahk_id %WindowUniqueID%
    ControlTextSize = 16
    VarSetCapacity(ControlText, ControlTextSize)
    SendMessage, 0xD, ControlTextSize, &ControlText,, ahk_id %ControlHWND%  ; 0xD is WM_GETTEXT.
    If (ControlText="Immediate")
        Send {F7}
    Else
        Send ^g
    Return
#IfWinActive
```

First, the script creates a context-sensitive <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> hotkey that requires the VBA IDE to be the active window (`#IfWinActive ahk_class wndclass_desked_gsk`).

When you press <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>, the script checks to see if the title of the current control is "Immediate".  If it is, then it sends an <kbd>F7</kbd> which sends the focus back to the code.  Otherwise it reissues the <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.